# How to add multiple volumes in vssadmin create shadow

Tags: windows, shadows

I am trying to create VSS shadow as below

```
vssadmin create shadow /for=C:
```

above worked fine but now for multiple volumes it is not working

```
vssadmin create shadow /for=C:,D:,E:
```

Comment: Have you tried `/for=C: /for=D: /for=E:` ?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Yes i tried it didnt worked it displays usage